sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
I have an app that uses sqlalchemy to manage a sqlite database. The app was created using pyqt5 and I have created all the classes for the database. Now I am in the process of create an .exe file using pyinstaller. In the dist folder I have the .exe file and when I run it this error appears:
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

I have been searching in the web for a solution and I have found this error is because an extra forwardslash in the uri, but that is not my case (must be three as I show below). This is the code where I upload the db in my app (when I run it using python everything is ok, but not with the .exe file)
ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)

SQLITE_DATABASE_URI = os.path.join(ROOT, "/model/database.db")

ICONS_WIDTH = 40
ICONS_HEIGHT = 40

BG_WIDTH = 1920
BG_HEIGHT = 1080

try:
    from ctypes import windll

    myappid = "isDev.sistemaGestorUrimare.administrativo.version1.0" 
    windll.shell32.SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    theme_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Sistema Gestor Urimare")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(":/logo/logo.png"))
        self.setStatusBar(QtWidgets.QStatusBar(parent=self))

        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings("Urimare", "urimareApp")

        if not self.settings.contains("theme"):
            self.settings.setValue("theme", "/resources/light")

        # self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///model/database.db", echo=False)
        self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + SQLITE_DATABASE_URI, echo=False)

        if not os.path.isfile(ROOT + "/model/database.db"):
            Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

        Base.metadata.bind = self.engine

In this post the user had the same problem and someone try a solution but I don't really understand it and they don't post if the solution even worked.
This is my .spec file content:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        ("resources", "resources"), 
        ("resources.qrc", "."), 
        (r"model\database.db", "model"),
        (r".venv\Lib\site-packages\qtstylish\compiled", "qtstylish\compiled")
    ],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='urimare',
    icon=r".\resources\iconosApp\urimareIcono01.ico",
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='urimare',
)

Thanks in advance!

I believe the issue with your code is that when your app compiles to .exe it doesn't also copy the db file. A fix could be to copy the db file to the new folder, however if sqlite cannot find the db file it automatically creates a new db file.
This brings me to another conclusion that your app does not have permission to create a db file.
Solution 1: Copy the db file to the folder of the compiled exe
Solution 2: If you want the db file to be created automatically when the app starts for the first time and do not which to copy the db file, ensure that your app has a write permission.

I forgot to post my .spec file. I have already edited my post to include it. Yes, I copy my database when I create the .exe file. Searching in another posst with the same problem they tried to give permissions of writing and reading in the folder that contains the db (I have already done it) and use the absolute path (same)

I could solve my problem using absolute path in
ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)
SQLITE_DATABASE_URL = os.path.join(ROOT, "model", "database.db")
self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///" + SQLITE_DATABASE_URL, echo=False)

instead of
self.engine = create_engine("sqlite:///model/database.db", echo=False)

